# How is "auto-open DevTools for popups" supposed to work?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have not been able to get breakpoints inside popup windows to be hit by this feature, which seems to be the reason the feature was created.

I've created an online test case (I can't think of another way to do it, given that it would involve multiple files and a popup, but if someone has a suggestion, perhaps I could improve the question). Go to:

http://www.inonit.com/chromium/issue-410958/index.html

That loads an index page that has a popup window with an embedded script. If I open DevTools, enable the option, and click the button to create the popup, it does indeed open the popup with DevTools open. But now if I go and set a breakpoint in popup.js on line 2, and close the popup, and click the button to open the popup again, the breakpoint is not hit.

Is that the intent? As I read the [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958) and its comments, it seems as though my breakpoint should be triggered, as that seems to be a substantial portion of the motivation behind this feature.

Comment: This is still true as of Chrome 61.

Comment: Still true as of Chrome 87.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running Chrome with the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag.

My guess is that after opening DevTools it takes some time to re-create all the previous breakpoints.

However, event listener breakpoints seem to be created quickly enough. So you can tell Chrome to pause on the first statement of any evaluated script. If you click resume after that the previously created line breakpoint is hit.

[image: Break on first statement]

Comment: I'm not running with that flag, but rather using the DevTools setting.

You provide an excellent workaround, which works on the test case I provided. (I can imagine it might break down on a large example, because there'd be an awful lot of breakpoints hit if you broke on every script.) Still can't figure out the underlying problem (and am still hoping to figure it out).